# Google Auth in Realm Cloud

Tags: ios, oauth, realm, jwt

I'm trying to integrate Google SignIn into my iOS app that uses Realm to manage users. I’ve signed into Google and retrieved my user. I’m ready to send my token to my Realm Cloud instance to get a `SyncUser`. I’m on the Authentication page of my Realm Cloud dashboard. I’ve got the JWT tab open.

And I have no idea what the heck to do now. Googling around isn’t helping because I don’t know precisely what I’m looking for.

Please help!

Edit: https://docs.realm.io/platform/using-synced-realms/user-authentication/additional-providers seems to indicate that Realm Cloud cannot use Google or Facebook authentication? That seems crazy.
BUT, that’s actually sort of okay with me, since once I get a SyncUser I “convert” them an object of my custom class `YpbUser` for my app’s purposes. If I’m storing all the user’s actual usable info in my realm as a `YpbUser` object, can I just use an Anonymous `SyncUser` authentication?

Comment: Are you still having an issue with this? Let me know, I can help you.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, I've set everything up, followed directions, and I was running on 10.0.0beta2, noticed that 10.0.0beta4 has added code for Apple authentication, so it's possible that RealmSwift just doesn't support google sign in just yet even though the documentation claims to

Comment: @rs7 app.login(withCredential: AppCredentials.init(googleToken: gToken!)) is as close as I can get in 10.0.0beta2 to the documented code on https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/authenticate/
The tutorial for setting up RealmSwift suggested 10.0.0beta2 for context, is it safe to just use 5.3.6?  I would have to change a lot of code since a lot of class/functions names are different

Comment: @FaultyJuggler I'm not sure.